# Combining overlapping polygons and values using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.7

I am using ArcMap 10.7.

I have 10, 15, and 30 minute pedestrian service areas for parks (pictured). I ran zonal statistics on the service areas with US Census demographic information. I would now like to know the total number of black, white, Asian, etc. people who live within a 10, 15, and 30 minute walk of a park, but many of the service areas overlap.

How would I go about counting the population in the overlapping areas only once?

[image: parks and service areas]

I've looked at merge and dissolve, but unless I'm misunderstanding, neither seem to do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different aspects you need to consider when solving this problem.

1. Make your service areas not overlap with each other. To do this, when creating the service area's polygon output set the multiple facilities parameter to "not overlapping" (i.e. service areas will get cut off where they meet so no area falls under 2+ service areas), and set the Overlap Type to Rings (so for any given park you'll get separate rings for 0-10, 11-15, and 16-30 min).
2. How are you apportioning the Census data to service areas when the Census area (block? block group?) does not fall completely within a single service area. The easiest solution is to assume that the population is evenly distributed across the Census area, so that if the service area covers half the area of the Census region it also covers half the population. However as the [Modifiable Area Unit Problem (MAUP)](https://www.gislounge.com/modifiable-areal-unit-problem-gis/) explains, this is not always a safe assumption to make.

Comment: I am apportioning Census data using rasters created with the USGS dasymetric map tool. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Great, then it sounds like you've already taken care of the second part of my answer, and just needed to know how to break the service areas into non-overlapping rings. Good luck with your project!